# Dismissing Error Dialog in Flutter: not working, it pops the parent widget or current page(Removes the curent page)

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, loading

I rann to a problem when I was working in my project.
I am trying to register a doctor to a database through an API. When I click the register button I want it to shows a loading dialog to wait till the API response, then I want to show an Error Dialog if an error occurred.

- I use provider to notifies listener through Consumer, not using FutureBuilder.
- I made the loading and error dialogs custom stateless widgets.
- I want to show loading dialog when calling the API and showing an error dialog if an error occurred and doing that with separating business layer from presentation layer.

But then when the I tried to dismiss (clicking on the ok button on the error dialog) the error dialog it pops from the parent widget or current page, **it removes the page.**

Below are an example of what I tried.

1- User Provider;

- I tried wrapping the error dialog with Builder widget but it didn't work.
- In the home page, that part that use Consumer you can't use `showDialog()` method or `showSnackbar` method, it required returning a widget.

This link is a Dartpad example to run and edit: https://dartpad.dev/?id=87bd2aae2f549c10201c02996fd1e10f

Below are an Example of what I tried.

1- Main method and HomePage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => UserProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late UserProvider _userProvider;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: true);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Consumer<UserProvider>(
              builder: (context, notifire, child) {
                if (notifire.state == NotifireState.initial) {
                  return const Text(
                    'Click To Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      height: 1.3,
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (notifire.state == NotifireState.loading) {
                  return const LoadingDialog(message: 'Wait for Response...');
                } else {
                  //return const RegistrationSucceededDialog();
                  return const RegistrationErrorDialog(
                    errorMessage: 'problem Message',
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: true).registerUser('User');
                _userProvider.registerUser('User');
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Register',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2- User Provider:

```
enum NotifireState { initial, loading, loaded }

class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  //final AbstractHttpUserRepo _httpUserService = HttpUserService();

  NotifireState _state = NotifireState.initial;
  NotifireState get state => _state;
  void _setState(NotifireState state) {
    _state = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // // One User
  late User _user;
  User get user => _user;

  void _setUser(
    User user,
  ) {
    _user = user;
  }

  // // Multiple Users
  late User _users;
  User get users => _users;

  void _setUsers(
    User users,
  ) {
    _users = users;
  }

  Future<void> registerUser(
    User user,
  ) async {
    _setState(NotifireState.loading);

    // // call the api to register
    // final userCreateResult = await _httpUserService.create(user);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    // // Set the user
    // _setDoctor(userCreateResult);

    _setState(NotifireState.loaded);
  }
}
```

3- Error Dialog Stateless Widget:

```
class RegistrationErrorDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String errorMessage;
  const RegistrationErrorDialog({
    Key? key,
    required this.errorMessage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextStyle _buttonsTextStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
  );

  final TextStyle _textStyle = const TextStyle(
    height: 1.3,
    fontSize: 16.7,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.error_rounded,
        size: 45,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      iconPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 10),
      actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, bottom: 10),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'An Error Occurred While Registrating The Accout:',
            style: _textStyle,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(
            errorMessage,
            // softWrap: false,
            style: _textStyle,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Ok',
            style: _buttonsTextStyle,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

4- And Loading dialog:

```
class LoadingDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  const LoadingDialog({
    Key? key,
    required this.message,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextStyle _textStyle = const TextStyle(
    height: 1.3,
    fontSize: 16.7,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
      iconPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 10),
      actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, bottom: 10),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(
            message,
            style: _textStyle,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to show Loading dialog when calling the Api and showing an error dialog if an error occurred and doing that with separating business layer from Presentation Layer.

Answer (score 0):

you cant return the widget as `AlertDialog`. thats not how to use and show a dialog.

read this official example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

you have to use `showDialog` method and then use the `AlertDialog` in it.

```
showDialog<String>(
   context: context,
   builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
     title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
     content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
     actions: <Widget>[]
```

`showDialog` is a future method. and `Navigator.pop` will dismiss the dialog.
if your dismiss the `AlertDialog` without that method, you are navigating the route with null stack. and thats why nothing show then.

Comment: Yeah that's right, but how can you show Loading dialog when calling the Api and showing an error dialog if an error occurred? I want to sperate business layer from Presentation Layer.